# How to apply custom fonts on android with androidx

Tags: java, android, xml, fonts

I want to apply custom fonts on my android app which is using androidx (not support library!!)

But all of the ways for this that i found by searching are for support library.

They say that use android.support.v7.widget.appcompatTextview. But I have to use androidx.

I tried a lot of things

1. using both

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/custom_font_family</item>
<item name="fontFamily">@font/custom_pen_font_family</item>
```

2. For applying all API level.  custom_font_family.xml of /font

```
android:font="@font/nanumbarunpen"
android:fontStyle="normal"
android:fontWeight="400"
app:font="@font/nanumbarunpen"
app:fontStyle="normal"
app:fontWeight="500" />
```

3. set a value to attribute of the widget directly.

```
<TextView
android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font_family"
.../>
```

even those attempts, it was all ignored.

But! preview display custom font correctly! (still no changes in my real phone...)

help me....please,,,,....... TT

Comment: Are you setting anything programmatically to that text view? Like a style.

Comment: If i set font to TextView with Typeface, It is working. But actually I need to change the font of the entire app... so this way is little difficult

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice any difference between `androidx` and the `support library` before.
You can add font folder under `res`, import your fonts and use them like below:

```
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/iransans_fanum"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Are you sure that you don't set any style programmatically ?

Comment: @ Did you try this?

Comment: If i use android.support.v7.widget.appcompatTextview, It makes errors with inflate

Comment: @kim-seonggyu can you plz post your java and xml layout ?